# Adding 0 to a date in sqlite

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am trying to get my values sorted ascending but although I get the results, it is not sorted properly as seen below:

```
"50","2016-12-1","2016-12-01 17:42:30","2016-12-01 17:42:30","0","0"
"50","2016-12-10","2016-12-10 07:31:43","2016-12-10 07:31:43","0","0"
"50","2016-12-11","2016-12-11 04:27:35","2016-12-11 04:27:35","0","0"
"50","2016-12-12","2016-12-12 07:52:18","2016-12-12 18:02:47","10","10"
"50","2016-12-13","2016-12-13 07:28:22","2016-12-13 18:18:31","10","50"
"50","2016-12-14","2016-12-14 07:32:34","2016-12-14 18:37:09","11","4"
"50","2016-12-15","2016-12-15 07:14:15","2016-12-15 07:14:15","0","0"
"50","2016-12-2","2016-12-02 07:23:33","2016-12-02 17:37:22","10","13"
"50","2016-12-3","2016-12-03 07:49:27","2016-12-03 17:45:01","9","55"
"50","2016-12-5","2016-12-05 07:40:22","2016-12-05 17:32:29","9","52"
"50","2016-12-6","2016-12-06 07:41:43","2016-12-06 17:42:00","10","0"
"50","2016-12-7","2016-12-07 07:20:33","2016-12-07 17:40:51","10","20"
"50","2016-12-8","2016-12-08 07:22:02","2016-12-08 20:56:37","13","34"
"50","2016-12-9","2016-12-09 07:35:06","2016-12-09 18:11:18","10","36"
```

The 2016-12-2 is below the 2016-12-15. This is how I get this values:

```
SELECT uid, scan_date as 'Date' , min(scan_time) as 'Time In', max(scan_time) as 'Time 
CAST(((strftime('%s',  max(scan_time)) - strftime('%s',  min(scan_time))) % (60 * 60 * 24)) / (60 * 60) AS TEXT) as Hours,
CAST((((strftime('%s',  max(scan_time)) - strftime('%s',  min(scan_time))) % (60 * 60 * 24)) % (60 * 60)) / 60 AS TEXT) as Minutes
FROM tbl_scanTimes
GROUP BY  uid, scan_date
ORDER BY uid asc, scan_date
```

This is how I insert data into the sqlite

```
var sCommand = new StringBuilder(@"REPLACE INTO tbl_scanTimes(branch, uid, scan_date, scan_time) VALUES ");
sCommand.Append(string.Join(",", (from DataRow row in values.Rows 
let branch = _yard 
let empId = row[0].ToString().Trim() 
let scanTime = row[1].ToString().Trim() 
let date = Convert.ToDateTime(scanTime) 
let oDate = date.Year+"-"+date.Month+"-"+date.Day
select string.Format("('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')", branch, empId, oDate, scanTime)).ToArray()));
sCommand.Append(";");
```

Is there a way that I can put 0 in the day part of 2016-12-1 so that it will be 2016-12-01? Thank you.

Comment: This is not one of the [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime). Change the data in your database.

Comment: The supported date format of sqlite is YYYY-mm-dd. 2016-12-1, I think, is the correct format. I get an issue when I try to sort the date. 2016-12-1 then 2016-12-11 then 2016-12-12.... It should be 2016-12-1 then 2016-12-2 then 2016-12-3.....

Comment: No, `dd` implies that there always are two digits.

Comment: Please see how i insert data into the database. Can you show me how to place 0 on the day part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following **CL's** comment on [supported date formats](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#datetime), I think that your data-inserting **may** be using your desktop dateformat settings, because you are passing `oDate` as just '{2}' in the format string.

Try using this format when you insert data:

```
string.Format("('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}')",
    branch, empId, oDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff"), scanTime)
```

(yes, I know that it can be packed into {2} expr, I just want it to stand out).
Btw. watch out for the upper-case MM and HH. It's important.
[Here's the full list](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Whever it works or not, check carefully what's the actual query you are sending to the db. Place a breakpoint on that line and see what the Format() method produces.